# Is there some way to use html in qml as I need?

Tags: html, qt, qml

I want to place my text so i can get something like:

```
"SomeText1 
SomeText2 One ... 
two ... 
three ..."
```

And I need to customize each of sometexts and 1,2,3 separately.
So I use the code

```
    Label{
        ...
textFormat: Text.RichText
        text: <html><b><div style='font-size: 12pt;'> SomeText1</div></b></html>+
    <html><i><div style='font-size: 12pt;'> SomeText2</div></i></html>+
    (here must be a function which back some big text)
        ...
        }
```

This code works great except one thing... It acts like ".simplefield()" and just "eat" all 2+ spaces and doesn't allow to use "\n". What can I do to change this?

Comment: what do you mean by "simplefield()"? You should follow HTML standard and use <br> and/or <pre>

Comment: it looks like your question needs clarification, now it's a bit unclear. Anyway, QML supports for subset of HTML 4, see it [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html)

Comment: @folibis, let me say another way. I want to know how to set my text on different lines using keyboard (in column, one by one). This function provides only TextArea component. But it doesn't provide html tags (if I add textFormat: Text.RichText to TextArea it will work like usual label). So that is the point. How to receiev html tags and the "setting-my-text-on-different-lines" function?

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. What does your "_set my text on different lines using keyboard_" mean? Besides the comment, what is you target. what do you want to do?

Comment: @folibis, found the solution. Check it. Maybe I gave a bad explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of my problem. When I type:

```
"1
2
3"
```

I see "1 2 3", but actually it is "1\n2\n3". My html-ed label doesn't react to "\n". So I just added a function in my .cpp, which replaced "\n" with "br". Here is it

```
str.replace("\n","<br>");
```

Comment: looks like you don't need `Text.RichText` but `Text.PlainText`. and so you don't need to replace `\n`

Comment: @folibis, but if i'll do this, i can't use html tags